How to query nested structs from joined tables with SQLX in Rust?
Assuming I have the following structs:
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, FromRow)]
struct PublicUser {
    id: Uuid,
    username: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, FromRow)]
struct PublicEvent {
    id: Uuid,
    name: String,
    owner: PublicUser,
}

And I'd want to query a PublicEvent from my PostgreSQL DB including the owner as a PublicUser and I have a column "owner_id" on PublicEvent, which references the corresponding PublicUser and must be set, how can I query this in one query?
I currently have this:
pub async fn list_events(pool: &PgPool) -> Result<Vec<PublicEvent>, anyhow::Error> {
    Ok(query_as(r#"
            SELECT "Event".*, "User" as "owner: PublicUser"
            FROM "Event"
            JOIN "User" ON "Event".owner_id = "User".id"#)
        .fetch_all(&pool).await?,
    )
}

But this results in the error the trait `sqlx::Decode<'_, Postgres>` is not implemented for `PublicUser`, which is required by `for<'r> PublicEvent: FromRow<'r, PgRow>` .
The only workaround I can come up with right now, would be to create a struct that holds all fields of both structs above, query into that and then impl From<HelperStruct> for PublicEvent, but that seems bad to me.
Is there an elegant solution to query an Event with its Owner in SQLX?
